# Comparar valores de um array

Tags: array, ruby

Tenho um array e nesse array eu possuo algumas datas, e preciso imprimir as datas que estão repetidas. Para obter esses dados eu criei um for que vai do tamanho do array, e dentro desse for eu fiz outro laço no caso um for também para poder comparar as datas, e dentro desse segundo for eu faço a comparação se as datas são iguais, e se for eu exibo.

Porem quando eu exibo há um problema, pois todas as linhas do array são exibidas, e também se houver alguma data repetida ele imprime a data a quantidade de vezes que ela repete por cada vez que ele encontrar. Sei que ficou confuso, vou postar a saída.

As datas que estão repetidas são `1981-04-11` 3x,  `1954-03-04` 2x e onde elas foram encontradas se repete também.

Exemplo da saída do código

```
HERMES 1981-04-11
HERMES 1981-04-11
HERMES 1981-04-11
MARCIO 1954-03-04
MARCIO 1954-03-04
LILIAN 1970-04-19
KLEBER 1967-12-14
RAIMUNDO 1981-04-11
RAIMUNDO 1981-04-11
RAIMUNDO 1981-04-11
FRANCISCO 1924-03-28
RUI 0002-11-30
MARIA 1954-03-04
MARIA 1954-03-04
MANOEL 1968-03-24
JOANNA 1981-04-11
JOANNA 1981-04-11
JOANNA 1981-04-11
```

Como está o código. `csv` é o nome do array:

```
for num in 0..9

    for num1 in 0..9
      dataAtual = csv[num][1]
      xatual = csv[num1][1]

      if dataAtual == xatual
        datas["nome"] = csv[num][0]
        datas["data"] = csv[num][1]
        puts datas["nome"] + " " +datas["data"]
      end
    end

  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'set'

# transforma em um array de uma dimensão
csv_temp = csv.flatten

# pega apenas as posições que possuem a data
csv_temp = (1..csv_temp.size).step(2).map { |x| csv_temp[x] }

# cria uma coleçao do tipo Set, que não aceita valores repetidos
repeated_dates = Set.new

csv_temp.each do |date|
  # adiciona a data para a coleção de datas repetidas
  # se houver mais de uma no array
  repeated_dates.add(date) if csv_temp.count(date) > 1
end

repeated_dates.each { |date| puts date }
```

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se compreendi corretamente seu problema mas dê uma olhada nesse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921999/ruby-how-to-find-and-return-a-duplicate-value-in-array)
Que responde um problema semelhante a mais elegante seria

```
ary = ["A", "B", "C", "B", "A"]
ary.select{ |e| ary.count(e) > 1 }.uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

Não percebi o output que pretendes, mas penso que o problema está no facto que o código compara a data de cada um dos objectivo com a data do mesmo objecto. Isto é, a data de [LILIAN, 1970-04-19] vai ser comparada com a data de [LILIAN, 1970-04-19], logo vai imprimir LILIAN 1970-04-19.

Mais uma vez, não sei qual é o output que queres, mas talvez isto resolva:

```
for num in 0..9

  for num1 in 0..9
    **next if num1 == num**
    dataAtual = csv[num][1]
    xatual = csv[num1][1]

    if dataAtual == xatual
      datas["nome"] = csv[num][0]
      datas["data"] = csv[num][1]
      puts datas["nome"] + " " +datas["data"]
    end
  end

end
```